# it block being called before the beforeEach block Jasmin

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I have an issue where in my beforeEach block I navigate to a specific URL before beginning my it block. However, sometimes the it block is being run before the beforeEach block is navigating to the URL. This causes a No Element found Error.  I have tried adding the done param but to no avail. Any help is much appreciate

```
  describe('Asset Manager [PREP]', function () {
    beforeAll( async function() {
      await Login.login( LOGIN.VALID.ADMIN.USERNAME,LOGIN.VALID.ADMIN.PASSWORD );})   

     beforeEach( async function() {
       await browser.get( browser.baseUrl + 'asset_manager/import' );
     });

  for ( ASSET in ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS ) {
   case_params( ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS[ASSET] );
  }

  function case_params( ASSET ) {
    it('Upload: '+ ASSET.UPLOAD_NAME + ' Asset' , async function () {
      let FTP = ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.FTP
      expect( await GlobalLayoutHeader.getAppNameFromHeader() ).toBe( 'Asset Manager' );
      var ImportAssets = AssetManager.ImportAssets;

      await ImportAssets.importFTPAsset(
                                    FTP.SERVER,
                                    FTP.USERNAME,
                                    FTP.PASSWORD,
                                    ASSET.FILE_PATH,
                                    ASSET.IMAGE_PATH,
                                    ASSET.UPLOAD_NAME + ' [RegressionPrep]',
                                    ASSET.DESCRIPTION,
                                  );
  });
};

1 Asset Manager [PREP]
   √ Upload: Black Panther Asset (3 secs)
   × Upload: Incredibles 2 Asset (0.587 sec)
      - Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, #import_type)
```

Comment: You say sometimes it fails but is there any pattern in the failures? Do the same script produce failures? If you run a single test does it pass or only seeing the failures when running multiple scripts?

Comment: No. I tried breaking it out of a loop and into separate it blocks however, this also caused failures. If i put in a break point and go through each step it seems to work. this makes me think its a timing issue. in the loop i call the it block 4 times first one passes second one fails and the next 2 pass. when watching it run i can see that at the end of the test it is supposed to navigate back to the main page but it doesn't causing the failure as the import button is not there to click.

Comment: I got it working by changing the way ImportAssets function works and instead of relying on the beforeEach block i just click on the button to go to the required page. Not ideal but it works. Still dont know how to solve the original issue though

Answer (score 0):

Did you check maybe there are errors. Maybe it is failing.

```js
beforeEach( async function(done) {
  try {
    await browser.get( browser.baseUrl + 'asset_manager/import' );
    done()
  } catch(e) {
    done.fail(e)
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, this also does not solve the issue. I have put a console log in the beforeEach and in the it to see if they are being called. They are being called as expected, the browser.get is just not being executed before my it block is trying to click on an element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could have an issue with you loop you are using. When iterating over the elements using a `for in loop` you should have the value from ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS saved in the ASSETS variable already. So when you call

```
for(let ASSET in ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS){
    ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS[ASSET]
}
```

You are essentially calling

```
for(let i =0; i < ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS.length;i++){
    ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS[ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS[i]]
}
```

So the same could be achieved with

```
for(let ASSET in ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS){
   ASSET
}
```

However that is a minor syntax issue not the cause of your actual problem. I've had some issues in the past with async actions in loops but do not have the clearest understanding of exactly why. That said could you try changing your `for in` to the following and seeing if it helps?

```
for (let i = 0; i < ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS.length; i++) {
    case_params(ASSET_MANAGER.REGRESSION_PREP.ASSETS[i]);
}
```